# Sefardic Wedding

Tags: three-weeks, wedding

Can an Askanazi (*who follow the rulings of the **Rema** who does not allow weddings during three weeks*)go to a Sefardic wedding (*who follow the rulings of the **Beis Yosef** who allows weddings during the three weeks*) that happens during the three weeks and what if anythig may he do when he is there?

Comment: Where do the Rema and Beis Yosef make those rulings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Askenazi may attend and fully paticipate in dancing at the wedding (Rivevos Epraim 6:298,Nattie Gavriel 14:10 FOOTNOTE 20)

Comment: The Ashkenazi custom is only to not MAKE a wedding, not to not attend one.

Comment: Just explaining the reason.  I know with regards to Sefira, R' Moshe even allows an attendee to shave and get a haircut if looking respectable would enhance the joy of the bride and groom.